# Serializing quickfix.Message with Kryo

Tags: java, serialization, quickfix, kryo

I'm trying to serialize a `quickfix.Message` instance using kryo serialization.

I'm using kryo version 3.0.3.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
    Message fixMessage = getFixMessage();

    Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
    kryo.register(Message.class);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Output output = new Output(outputStream);
    kryo.writeObject(output, fixMessage);
    output.flush();
    byte[] result = outputStream.toByteArray();
    output.close();

    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
    Input input = new Input(inputStream);

    Message fixMessage2 = kryo.readObject(input, Message.class);
```

and I keep getting this error:

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): quickfix.StringField
>   Serialization trace:
>   fields (quickfix.Message)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$DefaultInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(Kryo.java:1272) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstantiator(Kryo.java:1078) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1087) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:570) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:546) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]

if I register a kryo's `JavaSerializer` like this:

```
kryo.register(Message.class, new JavaSerializer());
```

I get this one:

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error during Java deserialization.
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.JavaSerializer.read(JavaSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]

I start to think that this object simply can't be serialized using kryo...

Any thoughts on the issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error says "Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor)" but I think you got around that and it's the 2nd error that's the issue. Doesn't the 2nd error come from the line:

```
Message fixMessage2 = kryo.readObject(input, Message.class);
```

so it did serialise and get across the wire. Can you show more of the deserialization error stack?

Comment: The next line in the error stack is: Message fixMessage2 = kryo.readObject(input, Message.class);

Comment: It's looking for a non args constructor on StringField, which is a class in use of Message. Both are classes of quickfix package, which I get from an external jar (not my code). I'm not supposed to (and can't) change it.

Comment: yes, but you fixed the non args constructor issue using that `JavaSerializer` and now the issue is doing the same on the deserialization step. Is there a way to use a `JavaDeserializer` on the `readObject` ?

Comment: Another thing is to question why your stakeholders won't allow you to add a non args constructor to StringField, that does nothing, and then recompile QuickFix? Nice learning curve in that.

Comment: Using JavaSerializer didn't help. I mentioned it as one thing I've tried and didn't work.
I'm trying to find a more convenient way instead of extracting, fixing and recompiling third party common code. Also no-one guarantees that once this StringFiled issue will be solved their won't be any other issues with serializing this quickfix package.

Comment: Hang on, I thought the non args constructor error was in line 3 of your code above, but the javaserializer error was in line 12 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): quickfix.StringField
```

You should have a no-arg constructor for all classes that are serialized.
If is not your class and you cannot change it, then you should create your own serializer like in [this link](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=708)